# Best way to dynamically update property values in distributed hosts (JavaEE)

Tags: java, distributed, distributed-computing

I need to dynamically update property values in different applications residing on different hosts (one host could have multiple different applications deployed). Different application may have different properties to update.

I am thinking about having each application open a thread just to act as a local server. Then use a centralized application to push out updates through sock connection. But is this too complicated? What if the connection is lost, recovery would be a problem.

Since this kind of problem is not really uncommon, I wonder if anyone knows any existing framework or tools to accomplish it in an easier and cleaner way. Of course, it has to work with tomcat.

Comment: Your push idea was reasonable. For connection loss management use TCP and transmit some "end of update indicator" as well. Have the clients only apply the update after they've received the end of update indicator. TCP will ensure that wither all data is delivered to the client or an exception on the sending side is thrown. Make sure the server has the ability to retry on failures. Make sure client has ability to roll back if there is an error applying a property itself. Keep it simple.

Comment: By the way your applications can act as client with your central one acting as server. They can initiate the connection to the server on startup rather than the reverse. May simplify management and implementation depending on your situation, if there's no issue leaving a connection open. Tradeoff is youd want to send periodic "heartbeats" from clients in this case to quickly detect tcp connection loss and recover. Server can ignore them though, no need for an explicit reply. Implicit Tcp ack is enough.

Comment: Thanks! What's the overhead to keep a connection open? Is this a common practice to keep connection open in a distributed system (for example, 100 servers with 20 applications on each server. That is 2000 connections to server)

Comment: Overhead is minimal, e.g. idle threads, sockets. Other methods could be an app on each server to distribute updates locally, with 1 connection to central. Or decentralized peer to peer model where updates propagate through. I can't tell you if those are overkill, sorry, no experience. 2000 to a single server seems manageable. Start simple then go more complex if you have issues. Well designed logic on app side should keep transport separate from the update and rollback mechanism itself, allowing you to drop other transport models in to accommodate future growth. That's my best advice.

Comment: (Good design will also let you quickly implement your basic update services eg with your central sever approach, just to get something out the door, without locking you into a specific strategy, so you can focus on potentially more important issues until after you've made performance and reliability observations through normal usage and testing).